# Create function in Python to Create a 3D Scatterplot from Training data

Tags: python, pandas, function, matplotlib

I'm new to Matplotlib and creating functions, but I'm trying to create a function called plot3Ddata, which accepts a Pandas DataFrame (composed of 3 spatial coordinates) and uses scatter3D() to plot only the **training data** (Columns x and y in my dataset below). I'm able to produce a 3D plot, but it's not a scatterplot, and it isn't limited to only my training data.  I appreciate any assistance as I'm not sure how to proceed.

```
First 5 rows of the data set which I read in as a DataFrame:
    x           y           z
0   6.550561    0.918746    5.056359
1   11.314821   0.675399    2.048655
2   0.001797    0.250325    4.429342
3   4.749025    -0.644546   0.565993
4   2.305234    0.024039    6.768186

## Here's my function called plot3Ddata which accepts a dataframe:

def plot3Ddata(df:pd.DataFrame):
    
    # Transform Pandas data into a format that's compatible with
    # Matplotlib's surface and wireframe plotting.
    
    index = df.index
    columns = df.columns

    x, y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(len(columns)), np.arange(len(index)))
     
    xticks = dict(ticks=np.arange(len(columns)), labels=columns)
    yticks = dict(ticks=np.arange(len(index)), labels=index)
    
    return x, y, xticks, yticks


Here I combined my feature columns (x and y) and reshaped them to a numpy.ndarray and also specified my label (z):

# Features
X = data[['x', 'y']].values.reshape(-1,2) # values.reshape converts dataframe (two brackets) to numpy.ndarray

# Label
z = data.iloc[:,- 1].values.ravel() 

Then I split out the data using train_test_split:

X_train, X_test, z_train, z_test = train_test_split(X, z, test_size=0.20, random_state=42)


Then I plot the data:

train_df = pd.DataFrame(X_train, z_train)
# plot3Ddata(train_df)

### Transform to Matplotlib friendly format.
x, y, z, xticks, yticks = plot3Ddata(train_df)

### Set up axes and put data on the surface.
# axes = plt.figure().gca(projection='3d')
# axes.plot_surface(x, y, z)

### Set up axes and put data on the surface.
axes = plt.figure().gca(projection='3d')
axes.plot_surface(x, y, z)

axes.set_zlim3d(bottom=0)
plt.xticks(**xticks)
plt.yticks(**yticks)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you plot a surface when you want a [scatter plot](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/mplot3d/scatter3d.html)?

Comment: That's a good question and I'm not entirely sure to be honest, other than I'm new and don't know any better.  Thanks for the direction.

Comment: Your y-axis looks also as if these values are strings and not float values. Have you checked this?

Comment: Thanks Mr. T.  Do they have to be float values?  Also, how can you tell they're string and not float? I see a decimal so I'd assume they're float.

Comment: It is just a guess because of the enormous number of y-axis labels. Matplotlib by default restricts the number of ticks to a reasonable number for continuous data but will plot all categorical labels (although one can force matplotlib to plot unreasonable numbers of tick labels - as I said, it is just a guess). In `x="7.3"`, x looks like a float number when printed but `type(x)` tells you, it is a string. To be sure, you have to check the dtype of your array/dataframe. I cannot do this for you, as I do not have your data.

Comment: Thanks Mr. T.  Great information.  I'll take a look.